# Angular tracking ng-model by that selected in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

So I have:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="beneSelect" 
        ng-model="item.id as claimInfo.benefitId in claim"  
        ng-options="item.descr for item in claim track by item.id">
     <option value="">Please select a benefit....</option>
 </select>
```

I am retrieving the right thing, but not pushing the right item out. Seems I need/want to have a dynamic ng-model and my shotgun approach and some research is not working as expected. Can I not have an expression in ng-model despite what the documentation says? In this case, I am get id and want to save as benefitID.

My code like this works, but does not give the property, but rather the entire object and it's properties:

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="beneSelect" 
        ng-model="claimInfo.benefitId" 
        ng-options="item.descr for item in claim track by item.id">
     <option value="">Please select a benefit....</option>
</select>
```

So where claimInfo.benefitId should return a single property, it returns the entire object in my JSON data.

With my second code example, this is what my JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "",
    "benefitId": {
      "id": "kj5PdPr74MxR17HWaLs%2bFQ%3d%3d",
      "planTypeId": 4,
      "benefitTypeId": 14,
      "benefCode": "HRADED",
      "descr": "HRA Deductible (1/1/2015 - 12/31/2015)",
      "askSecIns": true,
      "askResidual": true,
      "hasFunds": true,
      "startDate": "2015-01-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2015-12-31T00:00:00",
      "expenseTypes": [
        {
          "id": 94,
          "descr": "Deductible"
        }
      ],
      "dependents": [
        {
          "id": "kWOuvDLWk2965e6Y6cB4Tw%3d%3d",
          "name": "Yellow-TEST Ranger-TEST"
        },
        {
          "id": "%2fhCztDa9kyeJgjS61hB6yQ%3d%3d",
          "name": "Golden Ranger"
        },
        {
          "id": "R9Ml8nJlrhpj51fpuCN6gA%3d%3d",
          "name": "Beige Ranger"
        }
      ]
    },
    "isSecIns": "",
    "isNoResId": "",
    "expenseTypeId": "",
    "fromDate": "",
    "toDate": "",
    "provider": "",
    "who": "",
    "depId": "",
    "age": "",
    "amount": "",
    "comments": "",
    "isOffset": ""
  }
]
```

Notice how everything piles up under the benefitId property rather than just saving the property to the mapped property.

This next approach is better, but lose something along the way as my ng-show for the control below doesn't toggle as it should despite my efforts. The code relies on that pulled from ng-model set in control above assuming that the entire object is bound as:

```
                <div class="form-group" ng-model="claimInfo.isSecIns" ng-show="claimInfo.benefitId.askSecIns == true" required>
                    <label for="secInc">Do you have secondary insurance</label>
                    <div>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">yes</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">no</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the following :

```
<select class="form-control" 
        id="beneSelect" 
        ng-model="claimInfo.benefitId" 
        ng-options="item.descr as item for item in claim">
     <option value="">Please select a benefit....</option>
</select>
```

Which will store the id inside claimInfo.benefitId

Comment: Problem with this is it only returns the one property and not the entire object. I still need the whole object, but store the one item.

Comment: @Mark It looks like I misunderstood your question. What about this update?

Comment: This works better, but I lose the switches below in other form fields that rely on the object returned from what is selected above.